# Change the behaviour of Facebook notification jewel

Tags: facebook, canvas, request

Well, here is my problem, I have a game on Facebook canvas, my question is: when the player is currently playing the game on the canvas and he/she receives a game request through notification jewel or beeper popup, when that happens and the user clicks on the notification jewel to respond to the request the game reloads from the start and the player loses his/her progress, how can I prevent that from happening, I mean how to detect that the player is currently is in fact at the game canvas and he/she do not need to be redirected to the same canvas page.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle these links without reloading the page by defining a handler:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/bestpractice#internallinks

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.